# Batch to process the 3rd token and then append output as 4th token to the line

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I'm trying to modify a batch where the input file format has changed (due to circumstances outside my control)

The file used to contain only lines with a string which I had to run as a parameter after decode.exe
For example...

```
or71q238hdekb6gbq27ge56fz
```

But now the format has changed, the string I need is now the 3rd token (is that right? is that what I call it?) the string is now after the 2nd comma in the line like this...

```
date_stamp,IP_address,or71q238hdekb6gbq27ge56fz
```

But I need to keep the first 3 tokens (all the parts above) and then simply append the decoded string as the 4th token like this...
date_stamp,IP_address,or71q238hdekb6gbq27ge56fz,This_is_the_decoded_string

I'm thinking that's really not possible and I actually have to re-write the whole line to the output file, but I'm lost on how to accomplish this... nested FOR operations?

Here's the original processes that worked when it was just the string on each line by itself...

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (inputfile.csv) do "%cd%\decode.exe" %%A >> "%cd%\outputfile.csv"
```

Now I need something more like...

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%A in (inputfile.csv) do "%cd%\decode.exe" %%C >> "%cd%\outputfile.csv"
```

...but that doesn't seem to output all 4 tokens.

Update: new try...

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%A in (inputfile.csv) do (
   set date=%%A
   set ip=%%B
   set code=%%C
   FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=," %%D in ("%cd%\decode.exe %%D") do set decode=%%D
   set newline=%date%,%ip%,%code%,%decode%
   ECHO %newline% >> "%cd%\output.csv"
)
```

...but all I get is @ECHO OFF repeating in output.csv

Comment: With your latest update you now have a delayed expansion problem. You need to capture the out of the decode command with another `FOR /F` command.

Comment: Thanks, can I do that in a nested for loop, or do I have to use some kind of call / function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you need to add `"tokens=1,2,3 delims=,"`

`Tokens=1,2,3` says to allocate %%A, %%B, and %%C
`Delims=,` mean break on comma.

```
 date_stamp,IP_address,or71q238hdekb6gbq27ge56fz
```

`%%A` will have date_stamp
`%%B` will have IP_address
`%%C` will have your key.

See `for /?`.

VBScript is simple

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.StdIn
Set Out = WScript.StdOut

Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
    y = Inp.ReadLine
    MyArray=Split(y, ",")
    Set wmic = WshShell.Exec("cmd /c echo " & MyArray(2))

    Do While wmic.Status = 0
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop

    Decoded = Replace(wmic.StdOut.ReadAll, vbcrlf, "")

    Out.WriteLine MyArray(0) & "," &  MyArray(1) & "," & decoded & "," & MyArray(2)
Loop
```

Note you have to start the VBScript with CScript not the default wscript.

```
cscript //nologo "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Exec WMIC.vbs" <"C:\Users\User\Desktop\inputfile.csv"
```

and returns

```
date_stamp,IP_address,or71q238hdekb6gbq27ge56fz,or71q238hdekb6gbq27ge56fz
```

Change the command from echo to decode.

Comment: ok, that's helpful, thank you, I updated my new line but it seems to hang.  I guess now the question becomes how do I write all %%A, %%B, %%C and the output of decode all to a line?

Comment: @notAduck, you did not update it correctly per the answer you were given.  Your new code in your edited question now assigns %%C, %%D and %%E.  Do it just like this answer shows you.

Comment: I see that, I now realize the first variable should be %%A so subsequent ones start %%B %%C etc.
But it still doesn't output all tokens, only the last one which is the decoded token.  I am still playing with it, see updated question - thanks!

Comment: You can't simply do this. You need a second nested `for` loop that captures the output of decode.exe. Then in you main loop write all 4 at the same time.

Comment: Super, cscript outputting to a file works for me! Thank you!

Comment: Seems like nested FOR commands would have been a lot less code.

Comment: But unmaintainable.

Comment: @ACatInLove, what makes you say that?

Comment: `For` used to do one thing, process a list of files. IBM engineers decided to supercharge it for OS/2. But it had to run MSDos batch files. So they tacked on modes into existing commands. `For` is overloaded. It does many unrelated things (though all list based). You have to escape the `%A` variables. Issues with when variables should be expanded, which means multi-modes.